# validating textbox with a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a button and a textbox, i want to check if the textbox validation is correct and passed correctly when i click on the button. else the user should recieve a warning to check again what he had write in the textbox.

Comment: where is code you have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public bool Validations()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Error ");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // your code 
        }
    }
```

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
        if (!Validations())
            return;

    }
```

Comment: it's not preferred to use textBox within method ,maybe you could pass textBox or TextBox.text as input Parameter or the reference of the TextBox .

Answer (score 0):

Try using ErrorProvider. It may help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if something is wrong
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1,"Some Error!");
}
```